# GraphQL: Resolver for nested object types in graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql

Lets assume in the graphql schema, a UserType object is present:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'User',
    fields:() => ({
        id: {type:GraphQLString},
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        age: {type: GraphQLInt},
        friends: {type: new GraphQLList(UserType)}
    });
});
```

The following data is present in the database:

```
{
   "Users":[
       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "John Doe",
         "email": "John@gmail.com",
         "age": 35,
         "friends": [
             "3",
             "5",
             "7"   
          ]

       }
   ]
}
```

Query:

```
user {
   name
   friends {
      name
   }
}
```

As can be seen in the above example, the friends with ids are stored in the database.

How do I go about writing a resolver to get the user details (by id) plus details of all the users friends at the same time by sending a single graphql request?

Answer (score 1):

The resolver takes four arguments `(obj, args, ctx, info)`.
The first argument, in this case, `obj` has the result of the resolver from the parent's object (The parent resolver to the UserType). Therefore if you do `obj.friends` in the friends field's resolver, you will get the correct result.

Example:

```
friends: {
  type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString),
  resolve: (obj) => {
    return obj.friends
  }
}
```